# Django Admin in Production Mode doesn't load the admin page after login

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, production-environment

I am having some issues with my production mode. In this case, my login page in admin is not redirecting to the admin page after a successful login. I get the server response as: 200.

**[pid: 58|app: 0|req: 2/3] 172.17.0.1 () {46 vars in 976 bytes} [Wed Jun 22 14:07:32 2022] POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ => generated 2425 bytes in 40 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 12 headers in 623 bytes (1 switches on core 0)**

But, it stays in the same login page.  And, also shows a message: **" Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive. "**

Well... Already tried to understand if my superuser wasn't being created with hashed passwords. But, it is. I made a "python manage.py changepassword" to be sure.

I don't have any clue left to troubleshoot this.

Just to inform, I am using UWSGI and NGINX.

> Settings.py

```
    """
Django §ettings for myophio project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify
import environ

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG = (bool,False)
)

try:
    from ..logger_settings import *
except Exception as e:
    # in case of any error, pass silently.
    pass

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# False if not in os.environ because of casting above
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myophio.urls'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

LOGIN_URL = "/auth/login/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/auth/login/"

GROUPS_MANAGER = {
    'AUTH_MODELS_SYNC': True,
}

GROUPS_MANAGER = {
     # ... other settings
     'SLUGIFY_FUNCTION': lambda s: slugify(s, to_lower=True),
     'SLUGIFY_USERNAME_FUNCTION': lambda s: slugify(s, to_lower=True, separator="_")
 }


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'groups_manager',
    'guardian',
    'django_countries',
    'jsignature',

    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'api',
    'distrib_api',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [ # new
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', # new
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', # new
],
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]




# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = 'staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/UploadedFiles/')      
MEDIA_URL = 'media/UploadedFiles/'


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.CustomUser'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['api.backends.EmailBackend']
```

Comment: Is the issue that you are not redirected ? Or that you are not loged in ?

Comment: @NicolasMoreau the issue is that im not being redirected. It was working. is something that i did that maybe made it stop working. I don't know what probably made this. If i log in, in my initial login page it works fine.

Comment: @NicolasMoreau I figure it out. I created a model backend solution at the time but, it's not necessary anymore. And I was using it as authentication backend. After erase it, everything is working perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not manage to login at all. The message that you have indicates this:

```
Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff 
account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
```

Make sure you have the correct email address and password.

Also, make sure that the account that you are trying to login with **is indeed an admin/staff account** (you have to specify it when creating accounts beyond the first and default one):
[image: staff status checkbox]

HTTP response code 200 to a login attempt doesn't indicate success or failure of the login. It just means that your request was properly received and treated by the server, and you got the response.

Comment: Yes, I am creating with staff and superuser active. I also edited my question with my settings.py...if that could help understand better what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In production make sure you make the debug mode in `settings.py to FALSE`
and `ALLOWED_HOST =["*"]`
First write this command:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx.service
```

if this doesn' work then write this

```
sudo reboot
```

after this run

```
systemctl status nginx.service
```

this shoudl do the job